# Functions in C Error

Tags: c, function

So I'm not very familiar with functions since I just started to learn the C language. So far I have a program that reverses a string. How do you call the function in `main` properly? I am getting an error stated below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str[100];
    printf("\nEnter the string :");
    scanf("%s", str);
    reverse(str);
    return 0;
}

void reverse(char *st) {
    int i, j;
    char temp;
    i = 0;
    j = strlen(st) - 1;

    while (i < j) {
        temp = st[i];
        st[i] = st[j];
        st[j] = temp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
    printf("\nReverse string is :%s\n", st);
}
```

Error Message

```
reverse.c:12:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘reverse’ [enabled by default]
 void reverse(char* st) {
      ^
reverse.c:8:4: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘reverse’ was here
    reverse(str);
```

Comment: I know that the problem has to do with pointers but I do not know how to go about fixing it

Comment: Declare or define *before* usage.

Comment: Potential undefined behavior, fix it this way: `scanf("%s", str);` -> `if (scanf("%99s", str) != 1) return 1;`